# CEF Sharp remote debugging with chrome not working after chrome update(80.0.3987.116)

Tags: wpf, google-chrome, vue.js, remote-debugging, cefsharp

My Hybrid application created using WPF, CEFShaprp, and VueJS.

The CEF remote debugging was working correctly till chrome version 79.0.3945.130.
Upgraded to new chrome version (80.0.3987.116).

Once we do remote debugging when we hit URL in the browser it's identifying the web apps.

but on selection, it's redirecting to a blank page and in the console, we can see the below error.

```
Uncaught TypeError: document.registerElement is not a function at Object.UI.registerCustomElement
```

Please let me know anyone faced this issue?
any workaround to fix this issue?
any help will be appreciated.

Comment: See https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef/issues/2879/debug-console-error#comment-56113300

Comment: https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/issues/3049#issuecomment-584520071 make sure you've updated the references correctly.

Comment: Thanks @amaitland.I will try out the same.

Comment: Thanks, @amaitland, This issue got resolved on the CEF Sharp update.